# infile c++ not being read properly

Tags: c++

I am trying to read the contents of a txt file and save it to an array, however this is not being read properly/saved to my array properly:

Here is data.txt:

```
a
b 
c
```

Here is main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void readin(string file);

int main(){
     readin("data.txt");
}

void readin(string file){
   int myarr[10];
   ifstream infile;
   infile.open(file);
  if(infile.fail()){
      cerr << "Input file failed to open.";
      abort();
  }else{
    infile >> myarr[0] >> myarr[1] >> myarr[2];
    cout << "myarr[0]" << "\t" << myarr[0] << endl;
    cout << "myarr[1]" << "\t" << myarr[1] <<endl;
  }
   infile.close();
}
```

Here is what my results are being outputted as:

```
myarr[0]    0
myarr[1]    32767
```

Comment: It takes a bit of extra effort to convince `>>` to parse "a" as an `int`. The read fails so Crom only klnows whats sitting in `myarr`. Check the state of the input stream after reading to ensure the program read correctly. Eg: `if (infile >> myarr[0] >> myarr[1] >> myarr[2]) { //good. Print stuff } else { // bad. Handle error }`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the data type of myarr and the contents of data.txt.  How would you convert those lines to an integer?  Also maybe check the fail state of infile after doing the read.  Remember that if you just declare an array without initializing its values the array can contain any random number.